# Why does Swift Mailer not use my HTML template?

Tags: 8, theming, emails

In some form of my custom module, a condition triggers an email to be sent:

```
  public function save(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $entity = $this->entity;
    $status = parent::save($form, $form_state);
    $values=$form_state->getValues();
    if (($values['isurgent']['value']==1) && ($values['status']['value']==1)) {
      $iSeliste = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
      $oSeliste = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('person')->load($iSeliste);
      $sSelite = $oSeliste->firstname->value . " " . $oSeliste->lastname->value;
      $sAction = ($values['action'][0]['value']==0)?"offre":"demande";
      $sDueDate = $values['duedate'][0]['value']->format("d/m/Y");
      _sendEmailForUrgentService($sSelite, $sAction, $sDueDate);
    }
```

in sel.module:

```
function _sendEmailForUrgentService($sSeliste, $sAction, $sDueDate) {
...some code...
  \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail')->mail('sel', 'emailforurgentservice', $sTo, 'fr',      $params);
  \Drupal::logger('sel')->info('Courriel pour service urgent : envoi effectué.');
}
```

my hook_mail:

```
function sel_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $sFrom = '[redacted]';
  $message['from'] = $sFrom;
  $message['headers'] = array(
    'Content-Type' => 'text/html',
    'bcc' => $params[3],
    'From' => $sFrom,
    'Sender' => $sFrom,
    'Return-Path' => $sFrom,
  );
  switch ($key) {
    case 'emailforurgentservice':
      $message['subject'] = '[Le Grenier à SÉL] Un service urgent requiert votre attention...';
      $sBody  = $params[0] . " a posté une " . $params[1] . " urgente qui est valide jusqu'au " . $params[2] . ".";
      $message['body'][] = check_markup(nl2br($sBody), 'full_html');
      break;
  }
}
```

The settings of mailsystem are these:
[image]

And in my theme templates folder (mysite/web/themes/contrib/mayo/templates/), there is my email template `swiftmailer--sel--emailforurgentservice.html.twig`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">     table tr td {
          font-family: Candara;
          font-size: 14px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <table width="800px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <div style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                <p>
                    Chers S&Eacute;Listes,<br><br>
                    {{ body }} <br>
                    Vous pouvez la consulter <a href="http://lejardindepoissy.org/?q=sel_catalogue\">ici</a>.";<br>
                    Si vous ne la trouvez pas, c'est peut-être qu'elle a d&eacute;j&agrave; &eacute;t&eacute; satisfaite.";<br><br>
                    --<br>
                    Le Grenier à S&Eacute;L
                </p>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The email is sent. Everything is OK (From, To, Bcc, Subject) except the body!
Instead what I defined in the template, I have only the content of `$sBody` as defined in `function sel_mail()`.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: With Drupal 8.8, I've found that if you set $message['body'][] the template will not be used.  I'm not sure what that check_markup() call returns, so maybe it's related to that.  Just thought I'd make a note for anyone else that might run into this question, which works, but might get tripped up like I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mistake!
I put my email template `swiftmailer--sel--emailforurgentservice.html.twig` in "mayo" theme which is the theme the users of the site will see.
Mailsystem was set to use "current" theme.
When I made my tests, I did it as 'user 1' and the theme when the email was triggered was "Seven" (Administration theme).
I changed the settings of Maisystem:
[image]
And it works as expected!